# Webview url control using android volley

Tags: post, android-webview, android-volley, redirect, http-referer

I am doing a POST request to a url with headers set with a referer url and token. When I try to do my post using volley there are couple of redirects(307) which I handle as in code below. After redirects it returns 200. At this point, I want to laod the url in webview . This url asks for input from user so I want user to enter information and then on login I want to check when referer url is reached. How can I check referer url in this case?

Problem here is my initial url redirects and hits success 200 to my correct landing page that I am loading in webview below. But after that I do not have control on how can I check if I ever hit referer?

```
 public void authHttpPost(final Context context, final String id, final String url){

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
        StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://www.abde.com", new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                if(url.equals("https://example.org")){
                  // referer hit
                }
                loadWebView(url);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                // error
                NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
                int statusCode = networkResponse.statusCode;

                if(statusCode == 307 || statusCode == 302 || statusCode == 303 || statusCode == 304) {
                    TreeMap<String, String> headers = (TreeMap<String, String>) networkResponse.headers;
                    String redirectUrl = headers.get("Location");
                    Log.i("Redirect Url", redirectUrl);
                    authHttpPost(context,id, redirectUrl);
                }
                Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("Authorization", "Bearer "+mAccessToken);
                params.put("Referer", "https://example.org");
                return params;
            }
        };
        queue.add(sr);
    }


and my webview looks like below:

private WebViewClient webViewClient = new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            return false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        }
    };

    private void loadWebView(final String url) {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String postData = "token=" + Token;
                mWebView.setWebViewClient(webViewClient);
                mWebView.postUrl(url, EncodingUtils.getBytes(postData, "BASE64"));
            }
        });
    }
```